# Elastic search: Create tokens separated by either <space> or “-” and greater than 3 chars along with preserving the original field value

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

In my elastic search setup, I would like to create tokens separated by either " " or "-" and greater than 3 chars and also would like to keep the original field value. I believe pattern tokenizer can work but I am not able to create the regular expression.
For example: For field value as "This-is my token". The expected tokens are "This", "token" and "This-is my token".

I have tried the below index but it does not return the original value.

```
PUT m_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        },
        "default_search": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[^\\s-]{4,}",
          "group": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me in regular expression

Comment: Have you got any code yet? Does anything work? How?

Comment: Tried `"tokenizer": {"my_tokenizer": { "type": "pattern", "pattern": "[^-\\s]{4,}", "group": 0 } }`?

Comment: I have already tried this...this does not keeps the original value as token. So for the given example it will only create the token as "This", "Token" but I want "This-is my token" as well.

Comment: Then please add what you tried to the question, so that others do not suggest what you already tried.

Comment: Thanks...I have edited my question.